# Python: use generators to print 2d array

Tags: python, generator

I am new in python and I wanted to create a 2D array and print that one later.

```
self.values = [[0 for k in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
```

I've overwritten the `__str__(self)` method:

```
def __str__(self):
    s = (x.__str__() + "\n" for x in self.values).__str__()
    return s

def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()
```

The question is about the line, where i create the variable s.

I've tried a few things:

```
s = (x.__str__() + "\n" for x in self.values).__str__()

s = str((x + "\n" for x in self.values))

s = list((x.__str__() + "\n" for x in self.values))
```

In each case, I understand why it does not work but I can't find a way how this could work.

I am very happy if someone could show a way to use generators to create the string.

Greetings,
Finn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're obtaining a generator that will create a list that looks somewhat like `["1\n", "2\n"]`. You probably want to join that list:

```
''.join(s)
```

As `join` allows you to specify the joining string, you can leave out the `+ "\n"` from the generator as well and do:

```
return '\n'.join(str(x) for x in self.values)
```

See also https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join

Comment: join after the generator expression?

Comment: yep. that was it